# Best way to store vector of values into a map

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, stl

I've a map with the key as string and the value is vector of strings as follows

```
   std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string> > keyTable;
```

I've the following piece of code, to parse the value string and store them into the map. The values are separated by |. I need to parse them and store as vector of string into the map.

Thus, I've the following piece of code that does it. Is there a better solution to this in terms of speed and efficiency?

```
    keyTable.insert(key, std::vector<std::string>());
    std::vector<std::string>& valueVect = keyTable[key];
    boost::tokenizer tokens( str , "|");
    for ( boost::tokenizer::iterator tok_iter = tokens.begin() ; tok_iter != tokens.end() ; ++tok_iter )
    {
        valueVect.push_back(*tok_iter);
    }
```

Comment: `boost::algorithm` has something that will give you a pointer to each token, rather than a copy, but I don't recall it's name. Alternatively, you could `emplace_back` to avoid copying into the container.

Comment: Compiler version and name?  C++11 support?  There are some obvious improvements.

Comment: Visual C++ - Visual 2010

Answer (score 0):

From my view point, a better solution is not to use the boost library, as it adds overhead to your code. The following code will do the same work:

```
const char * begin = str.c_str();
const char * end = begin + str.length();
while (begin < end){
  const char *ptr = begin;
  while (*ptr != '|' && *ptr != '\0') ptr++;
  valueVect.push_back( string(begin, ptr - begin));
  begin = ptr+1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In pure C++03, this is about as efficient as I can get it:

```
std::vector<std::string>& valueVect = keyTable[key];
std::string::const_iterator b = str.begin();
std::string::const_iterator end = str.end();
while (b != end) {
  std::string::const_iterator it = std::find( b, str.end(), '|' );
  valueVect.push_back();
  std::string& newStr = valueVect.back();
  newStr.append( b, it );
  b = it;
  if (b != end)
    ++b;
}
```